# C++ Windows How to Open File From Memory

Tags: c++, file, memory, download

I am trying to download an updated file from the internet and open it. 
Currently I have it working by downloading the file to disk, I was wondering if it was possible to download the file to a char array and then open the file from memory somehow?

Sometimes my file will be an exe (to update the current program) and sometimes just a text file with new usage information.

Here is what I have to read the file into memory while downloading, but I'm not sure where to go next in terms of opening that file from memory.

```
    #include <ShlObj.h>
    #include <urlmon.h>
    #include <atlbase.h> // CComPtr

 bool downloadToMemory(){
    char* fileBuffer = 0;
    ComInIt init;
    CComPtr<IStream> pStream;

    // Open HTTP Request
    HRESULT hr = URLOpenBlockingStream(nullptr, host.c_str(), &pStream, 0, nullptr);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        DWORD bytesRead = 1;
        std::size_t total = 0;

        while(bytesRead > 0 && hr != S_FALSE)
        {
            // Dynamically increase buffer size 
            fileBuffer = (char*)realloc(fileBuffer, bytesRead + 4096 * sizeof(char));

            hr = pStream->Read(fileBuffer, sizeof(fileBuffer), &bytesRead);
            total += bytesRead;
        }

        // Do something here with fileBuffer 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get an IStream to a memory region, use SHCreateMemStream  for that. However if the 'file open' you want is actually ShellExecute to invoke the default behavior for that kind of file (as I would expect for an .exe) it will have to be written to disk somewhere.